# how do I executing JS loop returning multiple queries with Dataform

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dataform, sqlx

I have the following JS file in my dataform repo:

```
const values = ["4", "5", "6"];

values.forEach(value => {
  operate("operation" + value,{tags: ["test_operation_tag"]}).queries(
  ctx => `INSERT INTO table (test) VALUES (${value})`
 );
});
```

It return 3 operations with 3 different names (operation4, operation5, etc...).
As you can see in my code I'm adding a tag but it doesn't appear as an option for execution. How can I execute the 3 operations returned by this JS script? Do I have to create a dedicated `Workflow configurations` and select each operations manually?

Comment: Have you tried with a dedicated Workflow configuration?